# Asp.net MVC Access Custom Error Page Without Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.Net MVC project I have created a custom authorize attribute. If user is not authenticated my filter is working correctly. But when I in my login page and wrote a controller that is not exist I cannot redirect to custom error page.

This is my custom authorize attribute.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected virtual CustomPrincipal CurrentUser => HttpContext.Current.User as CustomPrincipal;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles)) return;
        if (CurrentUser == null) return;
        if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole(Roles)) filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
    }
}
```

Because of my default route my application is redirecting to Account/Index action

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl) { return View(); }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index2(string systemUserId, string returnUrl)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(AccountViewModel accountModel,string returnUrl)
    {

    }
```

How can I skip my filter for custom error pages ?

Comment: To clarify, you want to redirect to an 'Access Denied' page for pages (controller/actions) that don't exist?

Comment: Actually I want to redirect to 'Not Found' view. But I dont want to do it manually. Roles property in my CustomPrinciple is Null and because of this `return;` command is working. When I log in and try to access action that does not exist mvc handling this and redirecting to Notfound.

Comment: @YusufDuyar you can make this in web.config  `<error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to my `ErrorController` and problem solved.